# How to set ng-selected true?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have to show the user name which is saved in db as selected in drop down.

```
 <select name="field_user" id="field_user"  class="txt_box sel_box" ng-model="field_user_select" >
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Field User</option>
<option ng-repeat="user in field_user_list" value="{{user._id}}" ng-selected="current_user._id">{{user.owner_name}}</option>
</select>
```

How to do that?

Comment: what is `current_user` ?

Comment: For a particular folder am assigning user.. So if I already assigned It should be selected... Current user is already selected user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NgSelected waits for an expression. If it's true, it puts the selected attribute to the option. So you'll need to do something like:

```
<option ng-repeat="user in field_user_list" value="{{user._id}}" ng-selected="user._id === current_user._id">{{user.owner_name}}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ...  Working fine

Comment: Sometimes its not get selected

Comment: Well, check the values of user._id and current_user._id. Also, try with == instead of ===.

Comment: Instead of {{user.owner_name}} put {{user.owner_name}} - {{user._id}} - {{current_user._id}} to see what's different.

Comment: Thank you .. Issue is in fetching the data.. I have fixed the issue.